# Pytorch RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have one of the following scalar types: Long, Int; but got torch.FloatTenso instead

Tags: pytorch

Pytorch summary caused runtimer error. Following is the model. Runtime error occured while printing the summary of the model. I used torchsummary.summary in order to get the model summary.

Full Error message: RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have one of the following scalar types: Long, Int; but got torch.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)

```
class SentimentalModelV3(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, output_size, vocab_size, embedding_dim = 128, hidden_dim = 64, batch_size = 32, padded_seq_len = 10, n_layers = 1, drop_prob = 0.3, bidirectional = False):
    super().__init__()
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.n_layers = n_layers
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.padded_seq_len = padded_seq_len

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings = vocab_size, embedding_dim = embedding_dim)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = embedding_dim, hidden_size = hidden_dim, num_layers = n_layers, dropout = drop_prob, batch_first = True, bidirectional = bidirectional)

    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)

    #Linear and activation layer
    self.fc1=nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim * self.padded_seq_len, 64)
    self.fc2=nn.Linear(64, 16)
    self.fc3=nn.Linear(16,output_size)
    self.Relu = nn.ReLU()

  def forward(self, one_hot, hn, cn):
    embed = self.embedding(one_hot)
    lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embed)

    #stack up the lstm output
    lstm_out = lstm_out.reshape(shape = (lstm_out.shape[0], lstm_out.shape[1] * lstm_out.shape[2]))
    # dropout and fully connected layers
    out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
    out = self.Relu(out)
    out = self.Relu(self.fc1(out))
    out = self.Relu(self.fc2(out))
    out = self.fc3(out)

    return out

  def initCellState(self):
    h =  torch.zeros(self.n_layers , self.batch_size , self.hidden_dim).to(device)
    c =  torch.zeros(self.n_layers , self.batch_size , self.hidden_dim).to(device)
    return h, c
```

While, printing the summary, i got the error as shown below in the picture

```
from torchsummary import summary

n_layers = 5
batch_size = 32
hidden_dim = 64

model_v3 = SentimentalModelV3(output_size = 3, 
                              vocab_size = UNIQUE_WORD_COUNT, 
                              embedding_dim = 128, 
                              hidden_dim = hidden_dim, 
                              n_layers = n_layers, 
                              drop_prob = 0.3, 
                              padded_seq_len = 10, 
                              batch_size = batch_size,
                              bidirectional = False).to(device)

hn, cn = model_v3.initCellState()
summary(model_v3, [(1, 10), (n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim), (n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim)])
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like `input` is unexpectedly a `FloatTensor`. But I don't see anywhere in your code where `input` is passed to `model_v3`. How does the `summary` function work?

Comment: @kmkurn https://pypi.org/project/torch-summary/ this site contains the working of summary function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `summary` runs `model_v3` with `FloatTensor` of given shapes as input. But your code expects `one_hot` to be a `LongTensor`. The fix is to specify the correct tensor type to `summary`. Thankfully, `summary` accepts a sequence of tensors for this purpose:

```py
summary(model_v3, [
    torch.zeros(1, 10).long(),  # ensure one_hot is a LongTensor
    torch.zeros(n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim),
    torch.zeros(n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim),
])
```

Comment: After trying the suggested answer. I got following error.   TypeError: rand(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type Tensor at pos 2 @kmkurn

Comment: yes it is same code. @kmkurn

Comment: It worked. I was using old version of pytorch-summary and that is why it was causing error. @kmkurn

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the torch.cat or torch.stack with this problem " TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got float " or "expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got numpy.float32 "  or " TyprError: expected tensor as element 0 in argument 0 , but got int " to torch.tensor  and it will work .
worked for me .